# OpenGL just refuses to render anything, even though the data is correct

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, glut

I've been struggling with OpenGL after switching from Qt to GLUT with same OpenGL calls in the same places!  It's extremely weird that OpenGL stops working after this switch, I've tried every single method available on the internet with no luck.

It is also obvious that Qt does something to the GL Context which makes it work correctly without pain.

OpenGL Vendor:   NVIDIA Corporation

OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 430/PCIe/SSE2

OpenGL Version:  4.2.0 NVIDIA 304.88

Shaders: (Compile without any error):

```
static const char *vertexSource =
    "uniform mat3 proj;\n"
    "varying vec2 TexCoord;\n"
    ""
    "attribute vec2 texcoord;\n"
    "attribute vec2 vertex;\n"
    ""
    "void main() {\n"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(proj * vec3(vertex.xy, 1), 1);\n"
    "   TexCoord = texcoord;\n"
    "}";

static const char *fragmentSource =
    "varying vec2 TexCoord;\n"
    "uniform sampler2D texture;\n"
    ""
    "void main() {\n"
    "   gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, TexCoord);\n"
    "}";
```

Initialization of everything (Textures, shaders, ...) - This is called before the call to glutMainLoop() and after initializing GLEW:

```
static void initialize(void)
{
    sp_init(&sp);
    if (!sp_compile_shader(&sp, Vertex, vertexSource))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if (!sp_compile_shader(&sp, Fragment, fragmentSource))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if (!sp_link(&sp)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to link the GL shader program: %s\n", sp_log(&sp));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sp_bind_attrib_loc(&sp, Position, "vertex");
    sp_bind_attrib_loc(&sp, TexCoord, "texcoord");
    sp_bind(&sp);

    if (!texture_load(&grassTexture, "textures/grass.png")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load the grass texture.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    snakeTextures = calloc(sizeof(directions) / sizeof(directions[0]), sizeof(texture_t));
    if (!snakeTextures) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for snake textures\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; directions[i]; ++i) {
        char fileName[512];
        snprintf(fileName, sizeof fileName, "textures/snake_%s.png", directions[i]);

        texture_t tex;
        if (!texture_load(&tex, fileName)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load snake texture '%s'\n", fileName);
            continue;
        }

        snakeTextures[i] = tex;
    }
    currentSnakeTexture = &snakeTextures[0]; /* Looking right.  */
    point_make_data(&snakePos, g_width / 2, g_height / 2);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Setting the projection matrix and the call to glViewport in same place as it was in Qt (reshape):

```
static void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    //  Coordinate      Projection Matrix                   GL Coordinate (Transformed)
    //                  | 2.0 / width |   0.0           | 0.0  |
    //  | x  y  1 |  *  | 0.0         |  -2.0 / height  | 0.0  | =  | x' y' 1 |
    //                  |-1.0         |   1.0           | 1.0  |
    GLfloat projectionMatrix[] = {
         2.0f/w*g_zoom,   0.0f,      0.0f,
         0.0f,       -2.0f/h*g_zoom, 0.0f,
        -1.0f,        1.0f,      1.0f
    };

    sp_set_projection_matrix(&sp, projectionMatrix);
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    g_width = w;
    g_height = h;
}
```

sp_set_projection_matrix (is just a wrapper for glUniform...) & sp_set_vertex_data:

```
void sp_set_vertex_data(shaderprogram_t *sp, GLint attribLoc, const GLvoid *values, GLint size)
{
    return glVertexAttribPointer(attribLoc, size, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, values);
}

void sp_set_projection_matrix(shaderprogram_t *sp, const GLfloat *values)
{
    GLint loc = sp_uniform_location(sp, "proj");
    if (loc < 0)
        return;

    return glUniformMatrix3fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, values);
}
```

The render function callback:

```
static void render(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    double width = ceil((double)g_width / 32);
    double x, y;
    for (x = 0, y = 0; y < g_height; x += 32.f) {
        if (x == width * 32.f) {
            y += 32.f;
            x  = 0;
        }

        point_t placePoint;
        point_make_data(&placePoint, x, y);

        sp_set_vertex_data(&sp, Position, placePoint.data, 2);
        sp_set_vertex_data(&sp, TexCoord, texcoord, 2);

        texture_bind(&grassTexture);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);
    }

    renderSnake();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

point_make_data():

```
void point_make_data(point_t *__p, real __x, real __y)
{
    __p->x = __x;
    __p->y = __y;

    __p->data[0] = __x;
    __p->data[1] = __y;

    __p->data[2] = __x;
    __p->data[3] = __y + 32;

    __p->data[4] = __x + 32;
    __p->data[5] = __y + 32;

    __p->data[6] = __x + 32;
    __p->data[7] = __y;
}
```

Point::data is `double data[8];`

Main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(g_width, g_height);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutCreateWindow("Snake");

    glutReshapeFunc(&reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(&render);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (err != GLEW_OK) {
        printf("Failed to initialize GLEW: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
        return 1;
    }

    printf("OpenGL Vendor:   %s\n",  glGetString(GL_VENDOR));
    printf("OpenGL Renderer: %s\n", glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
    printf("OpenGL Version:  %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));

    initialize();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm sorry if I posted a lot of code but this is just to make it clear.

Please let me know if you need more code.

Comment: "OpenGL stops working after this switch". You have to be a little more precise. Does it crash? Does it just display black? Does it display the `glClearColor()` if you set it to something non-black?

Comment: @PeterT I seriously don't know what the actual problem is, debugging it using BuGLe and gDEbugger but nothing seems to be wrong...  It's the only thing I could think of.  Yes it displays black background.

Comment: black or `glClearColor()`?

Comment: It displays black background as expected from the glClearColor() call.  (I tried changing the colors to be red and it displayed red background).  It just won't render any of the loaded textures.

Comment: well, I feel silly walking people through the debugging process, but there's not much else we can gleam from this. Have you tried to just write a solid color to `gl_FragColor` to see if it's the textures? Have you tried to resize the window to see if the problem is with that the projection matrix isn't set? Have you tried  to set the projection matrix to the identity matrix and just render a tri with (0.0,0.0)(0.5,0.0)(0.0,0.5)?

Comment: Tried setting gl_FragColor to a solid color, doesn't render anything which means the textures are fine.  the reshape() function is called at the start of the program (Debugging using printf()) and before render() therefore the projection matrix is fine.  I'm not quite sure how to set the projection matrix to identity and render a triangle, could you provide a code snippet?

Comment: basically just replace `"   gl_Position = vec4(proj * vec3(vertex.xy, 1), 1);\n"` with  `"   gl_Position = vec4(vec3(vertex.xy, 1), 1);\n"` and make sure that whatever you're trying to draw is visible somewhere between (-1,-1) and (1,1). Also, my worry with the resize was that it was called before the shader was compiled and linked and therefore `sp_set_projection_matrix` might just return without doing anything. But I assume if you used gDEbugger that `glGetError()` is empty.

Comment: Nope, nothing is drawn.  "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" would you like to do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34307/discussion-between-petert-and-user9000)

Comment: Your shaders don't have `#version` specifier, so it's not 4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that `Point::data is double data[8];` so a `double[]` was passed to `glVertexAttribPointer` with `GL_FLOAT` as type which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
point_t *__p
```

Using any double-underscore prefixed names in your own code is undefined behaviour. These names are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Changed that to just be `p` but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz your brain isn't as good as you thought as well.  Please give explanation instead of just saying something that isn't informative.